# How to skip one element in numpy array

Tags: numpy

Suppose I have an array like:

```
from numpy import array
a = array([[[1,2,3]]])
```

How can I make right indexing to get a view array like:

```
array([[[1,3]]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

Just found solution.

```
b=range(3)
b.remove(1)
a[:,:, b]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `np.delete` function.  Unlike the list `remove` it does not act in place.  Instead it returns a new array.  And like your simple solution, it generates an index containing the items to keep (just does so for more general conditions).

```
In [1222]: np.delete(a,1,-1)
Out[1222]: array([[[1, 3]]])
```

`delete` code is rather long, but pure Python.  So it can be instructive reading.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use indexing:

```py
In [1]: a = np.array([[[1,2,3]]])
In [2]: a[:,:,::2]
Out[2]: array([[[1, 3]]])
```

Explanation: The first two `:` make sure you keep the whole two first dimensions, i.e., the outer two brackets. `::2` iterates over the innermost/third dimension and skips every second value.